# How to change width of Divider in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

On few screens of my SwiftUI app I am using Divider() between few elements. This Divider is rendered as a very thin grey (or black?) line. I am guessing 1 point. How can I change the width of Divider()?

Comment: You can use `.frame(width:)`

Comment: @Pigpocket This just makes it take more space, but *visually* it's still only 1 px.

Comment: .frame(width:, height:) only works if you set a specific .background(Color.something). And every three months I have to come back to this answer to remind me of that.

Comment: I don't think `.frame(width:,height:)` works for `Divider` even if you set `.background()`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can create any divider you wish, colors, width, content... As in below example.

```
struct ExDivider: View {
    let color: Color = .gray
    let width: CGFloat = 2
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(height: width)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I get it. So there are no modifiers to change width of the default Divider(), but I can create a custom one (as in your example) and use it instead? Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want to use this custom modifier with a different color or width you need to replace ‘let’ with ‘var’.

Comment: You don't have to use a custom Divider. Some of the other answers demonstrate how.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone interested, I modified accepted answer with support for both horizontal and vertical directions, as well as used original Divider colors with support for Dark Mode:

```
struct ExtendedDivider: View {
    var width: CGFloat = 2
    var direction: Axis.Set = .horizontal
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(colorScheme == .dark ? Color(red: 0.278, green: 0.278, blue: 0.290) : Color(red: 0.706, green: 0.706, blue: 0.714))
                .applyIf(direction == .vertical) {
                    $0.frame(width: width)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
                } else: {
                    $0.frame(height: width)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus, this snippet uses `applyIf` syntax:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func applyIf<T: View>(_ condition: @autoclosure () -> Bool, apply: (Self) -> T, else: (Self) -> T) -> some View {
        if condition() {
            apply(self)
        } else {
            `else`(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for iOS14 +

Comment: I use this in project, that requires iOS 13+ and macOS 10.15+

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
Divider().frame(maxWidth: 100)
```

That was about a third of the width of the screen on portrait mode on an iPhone 11.

Comment: If the divider is horizontal doing `Divider().frame(maxHeight:2)` would set the thickness to 2 points.

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @ngb You need to add `.background(Color.black)` in order to see the thickness

Answer (score 7):

This is way late but...adding a background color to height will present a thicker Divider(). The divider is still razor thin within the image but the desired effect works.

```
Divider().frame(width: 300,height: 10).background(Color.blue)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust the thickness of a Divider using frame(width, height) depending on if it is a vertical or horizontal Divider.
If you have a vertical Divider, then you can use frame(height: ?) to adjust the thickness. If you have a horizontal Divider, then you can use frame(width: ?). Along with setting the frame width or height you will also need to user the overlay modifier to give the Divider a color (even if you leave it grey).

example:

```
Divider()
    .frame(height: 5)
    .overlay(.gray)
```

*See this blog for more Divider customization

[https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-divider/#:~:text=of%20a%20divider.-,Adjust%20SwiftUI%20Divider%20Thickness,-SwiftUI%20divider%20has](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-divider/#:%7E:text=of%20a%20divider.-,Adjust%20SwiftUI%20Divider%20Thickness,-SwiftUI%20divider%20has)

Answer (score 2):

I found this works best...

```
        Group {
            Divider()
                .frame(height: 2.0)
                .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: 100)
```

once you place the Divider into the group, you can alter the surrounding area of the Divider by altering the Group

This would make the divider line 2 px high, and 100 px long

Answer (score 0):

```
struct AppDivider: View {
    var color: Color =.gray
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .frame(height: lineWidth)
            .overlay(color)
    }
}

struct AppDivider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            AppDivider()
            AppDivider(color: .red, lineWidth: 5)
        }
    }
}
```