# Why are my SwiftUI List Dividers not lining up properly?

Tags: user-interface, swiftui

I'm trying to properly line up my SwiftUI list but I am unable to center the list dividers. For some reason, the list seems centred but the dividers are aligned to trailing, not to the center.

I added some background colouring to the elements in an effort to debug it, but can't seem to find out a reason why this is happening.

There doesn't seem to be any padding blocking it either. Maybe it has to do with the list style?

[image: List]

Code below:

```
 List {
                    
                    
                    ForEach(savedpoems, id:\.title) {SavedPoem in
                       
                        NavigationLink (destination: DetailViewSaved(savedPoem: SavedPoem)){
                          
        
                            
                                HStack {
                                    
                        
                                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                        Text("\(SavedPoem.title ?? "")")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .lineLimit(1)
                                            .padding(.bottom, 3)
                                            
                                        
                                        Text("\(SavedPoem.author ?? "")")
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.trailing)
                                    .background(Color.orange)
                                    
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                }
                                .padding()
                                .background(Color.blue)
                            
                    

                        }.padding(.all, 0)
                        .background(Color.red)
                    

                        
                    }.onDelete(perform: remove)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                                    
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .background(Color.black)
          
                    

            }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Default list row separators are ... just default - Apple draws them as they think. If they do not fit your needs you can hide them (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598818/12299030) and just draw your own (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58787290/12299030)

Comment: So this is not an issue with my code, default line separators always align trailing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decrease the `.leading` `.padding` for your `List` it should even out.

Below is the sample from your code on where to put it (Bottom part)

```
.padding(.leading, -16)
    }//Something not Listed I placed a VStack
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
```